# How Do I return a candidate name even if the vote count is zero

Tags: mysql

```
SELECT 
  candidates.image as image,
  candidates.id as cid , 
  candidates.name as cname, 
  choice,
  COUNT(choice) as votes 
FROM `ballots` 
RIGHT JOIN candidates 
  ON candidates.id = ballots.candidate_id
WHERE ballots.position_id = $position_id
GROUP BY choice
ORDER BY choice DESC
```

How do I return a candidate name even if the vote count is zero?

Comment: Could you provide some sample data and expect result? that really help

Comment: You `group by` make no sense and you want to do `LEFT JOIN`?

Comment: Drive from candidates rather than ballots.

Comment: What does the column `choice` contain? Do you want to count certain choices or all? So far you are trying to count all choices that are not null.

Answer (score 2):

You should group by candidate and not by `choice`.
Also, the condition in the `WHERE` clause should be moved to the `ON` clause.
Finally, `LEFT` joins are easier to read.

Assuming that `id` is the `PRIMARY KEY` of `candidates` you can do this:

```
SELECT c.image, c.id, c.name AS cname, 
       COUNT(b.position_id) AS votes 
FROM candidates c LEFT JOIN ballots b
ON c.id = b.candidate_id AND b.position_id = $position_id
GROUP BY c.id
ORDER BY c.name;
```

or maybe you want:

```
ORDER BY votes DESC;
```